# Fatal error while upgrading Laravel 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I'm following the official **[upgrade guide](http://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)** from 5.1 to 5.2. First sub-section says:

> If you are installing a beta release of Laravel 5.2, add
>   `"minimum-stability": "beta"` to your composer.json file.
>
> Update your composer.json file to point to `laravel/framework 5.2.*`.
>
> Add `symfony/dom-crawler ~3.0` and `symfony/css-selector ~3.0` to the
>   require-dev section of your composer.json file.

Now, after I introduce the above changes and run `composer update`, I get the following error(s):

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider' not found 
in /home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146
```

and

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Class 'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider' not found
```

and

```
[RuntimeException]
Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/myproject/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146
```

The errors are thrown **after** the update is done, and "Generating autoload files" takes place.

**What might be wrong?**

It does not look like a custom package issue, but a core one. Should I continue with the upgrade guide and run `composer update` AFTER all has been adjusted to suit the new framework version?

**UPDATE**

Running `composer dump-autoload` afterwards **doesn't throw the errors** described above. Still confusing, though.

Comment: On a related note, future readers may want to check out [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com) - an automated upgrade tool for Laravel projects.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is no `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider` any more.

If I were you, I would compare my app project to `https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commits/develop`, if you for example look at `https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/develop/config/app.php` you will see default providers for Laravel 5.2:

```
Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Broadcasting\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ConsoleSupportServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Cookie\CookieServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Database\DatabaseServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Filesystem\FilesystemServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\FoundationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Pagination\PaginationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Pipeline\PipelineServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Queue\QueueServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Session\SessionServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Translation\TranslationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider::class,
Illuminate\View\ViewServiceProvider::class,
/*
 * Application Service Providers...
 */
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: Does this mean I can safely remove the entry from config/app.php?

Comment: It seems yes, but you should make sure the entire structure and file contents of `app` folder matches the new one from Laravel 5.2

Comment: OK, thanks. The upgrade guide actually tells me to remove it in the Service Providers section. Guess it's better to update composer dependencies after all the code and structure had been adjusted.

Comment: Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class and Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class should be removed in 5.2

Comment: @lesssugar yeah the upgrade instructions are ordered strangely

Comment: So what if you have removed them but its still looking for them? I think they may be cached as they are in my bootstrap/cache/services.json

Comment: I tried for many times, eventually I comment out `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,` and run `composer update`. only it works

Answer (score 22):

Remove the two service providers from config/app.php

```
Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class,
 Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class,
```

Answer (score 21):

In updating from 5.1 to 5.2 on existing projects, we found that running `composer update` before and after the removing the lines for the providers

`Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider::class  Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class`

was a necessary sequence to getting the laravel update to complete.

Running before would allow laravel to download and update the current framework library dependencies and then running after the removal (composer was able to complete without issue)

We also found that any value in the .env file cannot have spaces and must be surrounded with quotes to work.

Answer (score 10):

Updating the app.php file under config/ solved one problem but with the introduction of the bootstrap/cache folder you will probably continue running into the same error.

I ran the composer update Before removing the cached file so I kept hitting the same error. Make sure that you delete the bootstrap/cache/services.php file first.

There might be a artisan command for this but I totally missed this step in the documentation.

Comment: Thats help, use rm bootstrap/cache/*.php fix my error

Comment: This answer led me to solve my issue. Just removing services.php, I still got the error. What I had to do was also remove bootstrap/cache/compile.php. Everything was working fine on my localhost but not on a live server, removing these 2 cached files solved my issue. Thanks @adam!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0

**Service Providers**

The **Illuminate\Foundation\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider** should be removed from your service provider list in your app.php configuration file.

The **Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider** should be removed from your service provider list in your app.php configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

Remove packages.php and config.php from the bootstrap cache folder
after run composer dump-autoload