# Laravel 5.1 to 5.2 composer update error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

Whenever I try to run composer update I now receive an error with a root cause of the following

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher::mapUsing()**

I can confirm Laravel 5.2 is properly installed, as are all other dependencies. This only happens when php artisan clear-compiled is run.

I've also updated my base controller based on a suggestion from a few hours ago in the Laracasts forum

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;

abstract class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
}
```

But I still receive the error

UPDATE: This happens whenever the application is bootstrapped at all. My app won't even run now.

UPDATE 2, full stack trace:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher::mapUsing() in /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/app/Providers/BusServiceProvider.php on line 16
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/artisan:0
PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/artisan:36
PHP   3. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:105
PHP   4. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:208
PHP   5. Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:203
PHP   6. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php:17
PHP   7. array_walk() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:718
PHP   8. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:718
PHP   9. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:717
PHP  10. Illuminate\Container\Container->call() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:734
PHP  11. call_user_func_array:{/Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507}() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507
PHP  12. Cafe\Providers\BusServiceProvider->boot() /Users/Zara/Web/cafe/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher::mapUsing()
```

Comment: Looks like Taylor removed `mapUsing()` in this commit: https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/c659d98d14be053ca384a9cf63cb3ba9a64adc87

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395129/fatal-error-while-upgrading-laravel-5-1-to-5-2

Comment: Thanks @HardyMathew, but I've already removed the service providers. Still no dice

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the Laravel 5.2 Upgrade Guide

> Separate Commands & Handlers
>
> The Laravel 5.2 command bus now only supports self-handling commands and no longer supports separate commands and handlers.
>
> If you would like to continue using separate commands and handlers, you may install a Laravel Collective package which provides backwards-compatible support for this: https://github.com/LaravelCollective/bus

There is no longer support for non self handling commands which is what the mapper would be for; mapping commands to handlers.

**Check Service Providers**

Check any service providers you have registered to make sure they aren't calling that method on dispatcher. If still having that issue, you can try checking any package service providers to make sure they aren't calling that method.

Comment: That's the thing though, why do I need to install this package when performing a separate upgrade when I wasn't using this to begin with?

Comment: Installing that does not fix the problem.

Comment: Where is the error coming from? Something is trying to call that method.

Comment: I'll post the full stack trace

Comment: You have a BusServiceProvider in app/Providers that needs to be adjusted.

Comment: I haven't changed anything in that provider. What would need to be updated? Sorry if that sounds like a dumb question but I don't see it in the docs anywhere

Comment: Idk you have added that service provider to your project. It isn't a default one. Does that provider have a call to `mapUsing` in it ?

Comment: Nope, sure doesn't. It contains the binding for the auth registrar

Comment: There is no auth registrar in 5.1, 5.2. Is this a 5.0 project you upgraded ?