# Missing 'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider' class on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have updated the composer.json file as instructed on the upgrade guide on Laravel 5.2 Documentation and run composer update.

Everything was updated correctly, but composer dumped the error below while generating autoload files.

```
Class 'Illuminate\Routing\ControllerService Provider' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/homework/vendor/laravel/framework /src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 146
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fatal error while upgrading Laravel 5.1 to 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395129/fatal-error-while-upgrading-laravel-5-1-to-5-2)

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you remove `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerServiceProvider` from your `/config/app.php`.

https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade (see the "Service Providers" section)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with your composer.json.It may got corrupted. Make sure

"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
  },

exists.Then run composer update.

Comment: Question it's about Laravel 5.2 and your answer speak about 5.0 ?